# making sharp pixel perfect curves in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, pixel, anti-aliasing, rasterization

I'm trying to export a vector graphic to a png with full transparent alpha channel but i noticed that all around the edge of the curves the pixels are blended semi tranparent. I need full opaque cut next to full alpha. At first i thought it was export settings but then when i turned on the pixel preview in illustrator i saw this:

[image]

As you can see the semi transparent pixels seem to be inherent in the way illustrator is currently handling rasterizing curves cutting across pixels. Is there any way to make it so illustrator cuts pixels either full opaque or full transparent, instead of this semi transparent blend?

Comment: The technical term for this is anti-aliasing. You might find an answer in between one of [these questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=illustrator+export+aliasing)

Comment: I dont think pixel perfect measn what you think it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch off anti-aliasing when you export as PNG.

Here's an example

[image]